# Automatic slider with ngFor

Tags: angular

I have this array of images in my component.ts:

```
images = [
  "https://content.xxx/50/front-page/background1.jpg", 
  "https://content.xxx/50/front-page/background2.jpg", 
  "https://content. xxx/50/front-page/background3.jpg"
];
```

And this div in my component.html:

```
    <div class="slider">
    
          <div class="slider-container" *ngFor="let item of images">
       
             <figure>
          
                 <img [src]="images" class="img-responsive"/>
       
             </figure>
                                                                                 
          </div>

    </div>
```

My problem is that I only see the first image in the slider.

Before I had this in the component.html and I saw the three images but when passing it to array I only see the first one.

```
<div class="slider">
           <div class="slider-container">
               <figure>
                   <img src="https://content.xxx/50/front-page/fondo1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
               </figure>

               <figure>
                   <img src="https://content.xxx/50/front-page/fondo2.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
               </figure>

               <figure>
                   <img src="https://content.xxx/50/front-page/fondo3.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
               </figure>
                                           
            </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

In the question I have put what I expected and what I have tried

Comment: `[src]="item"`, see that is the variable over you iterate in the *ngFor="let item of images"

Comment: plus, the `ngFor` is in the `slider-container`, which means you will have multiple containers in your html, you could use ng-container or move the ngfor to the below figure node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust your code to use `*ngFor` directive in your `figure` tag in order to achieve what you had before, only dymanically:

```
<div class="slider">
    
          <div class="slider-container">
       
             <figure *ngFor="let item of images">
          
                 <img [src]="item" class="img-responsive"/>
       
             </figure>
                                                                                 
          </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: If my answer did help you, please remember to accept it and close the question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong image src, pass "item" instead of images, Like this.

```
  <div class="slider">
          <div class="slider-container" *ngFor="let item of images">
             <figure>
                 <img [src]="item" class="img-responsive"/>
             </figure>                                                                      
          </div>
    </div>
```